# NodeJs Use async with for loop download

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, async.js

I have this loop for download some files and it's work fine.

But the files are downloaded like "2,3,4,1,5" order and not "1,2,3,4,5".

I know how to do .each async and waterfall async but I don't know how to do for this loop.

```
Config.TotalFiles = 5;

for(i = 1; i <= Config.TotalFiles; i++) {
   $this.CreateJSONFile(i, function() {
     cls();
   });
}
```

And when downloads are done I want to call my callback, I have tried this `if(id == Config.TotalFiles)` but it's doesn't work because the id isn't good.

How can I done an "async" process with this loop?

Thanks

Comment: `async.times` ?

Comment: I have always "1,5,3,4,2"...

Comment: That depends on how fast each `CreatJSONFile` call does its job. They're *started* in the expected order always. If you want to ensure they also end in the expected order, your only choice is to do it sequentially instead of in parallel (using the `…Series` methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async.whilst for this:

```
Config.TotalFiles = 5;
var count = 1;

//pass your maincallback that you want to call after downloading of all files is complete.

var callMe = function(mainCallback){
    async.whilst(
        function() { return count <= Config.TotalFiles; },
        function(callback){
            $this.CreateJSONFile(count, function() {
                cls();
                count++;
                callback();
            });
        }, function(){
           //This function is the final callback
           mainCallback();
        })
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I want just a number (81) ^^

Comment: You can check my edited answer. It will do the work.

Comment: I'm going to answer some questions in a few hour, I need 15 reputation for upvote ^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to implement async for-loop. The main idea is to call callback (like continue), when current step has been completed. You may use some helpful library as mentioned above (async.js). But you also have to understand that it will not be done in parallel (so the time to complete the downloads will be increased).

These are some nice examples to help you: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#whilst

Comment: Can you check my answer please? I have added more code

Answer (score 0):

Check my screen please for understand my case.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/azHUA.jpg

Or this pastebin https://pastebin.com/jtANeSxq

```
                cls();
                for(i = 1; i <= Config.TotalFolders; i++) {
                    $this.CreateJSONFile(i, function() {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            cls();
                        }, 200);
                    });
                }

    CreateJSONFile(id, callback) {
    console.log(chalk.hex("#607D8B")(`Creating JSON Files... [${id}/${Config.TotalFolders}]`));
    var requestOptions = {
        encoding: "binary",
        method: "GET",
        uri: `${Config.Url.Source}${Config.Url.Audio}` + `${id}/skeud.json`
    };
    request(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            if(!fs.existsSync(Config.DownloadsPath + `${id}/skeud.json`)) {
                fs.writeFile(Config.DownloadsPath + `${id}/skeud.json`, body, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(chalk.hex("#FFEB3B")(`JSON File ${chalk.inverse(id)} ${chalk.hex("#FFEB3B")("created")}`));
                });
            } else {
                console.log(chalk.hex("#FFEB3B")(`JSON File ${chalk.inverse(id)} ${chalk.hex("#FFEB3B")("skipped")}`));
            }
        }
    });
    /*if(created == Config.TotalFolders) {
        callback();
    }*/
}
```

Thanks